# Accessing parent function parameter

Tags: javascript

I've got the following code:

```
function xyz() {
    this.particles = [];

    this.particle = function (x, y, velocityX, velocityY, color) {
        this.x = x || 0;
        this.y = y || 0;
        this.velocityX = velocityX || 0;
        this.velocityY = velocityY || 0;
        this.color = color || "#000000";
        this.next = function () {
            this.x += this.velocityX;
            this.y += this.velocityY;
        };
    };

    this.drawParticles = function (particleArray) {
        particleArray = particleArray || /* I WANT TO HAVE particles here */;
    }
}
```

In drawParticles I want to access the array I defined in the parent function. Could someone tell me how I do that?

Comment: Just use `this.particles`?  Or are you trying to access something else?

Comment: um, `this.particles`??

Comment: Did you try using `this.particles`?  If you did, and it didn't work, can you show how you're calling `drawParticles`, because that might be what's making it not work.